# Where to run the copy command for Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have been running in circles trying to figure out 'where' to run the COPY command for Amazon Redshift from. All the documentation just says "run the COPY command" without actually stating where to run it from.

I have downloaded AWS CLI; I have configured SQL Workbench and connected it to Redshift. I have logged into Redshift service. No where do I see a place where I can input the COPY command.

Even google search just throws up "run the COPY command".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amazon Redshift presents itself as a PostgreSQL database. The `COPY` command is an extension of SQL supported by Redshift. Therefore, the `COPY` command needs to be issued from an SQL client.

You mention that you have configured SQL Workbench. Once you connect to the Redshift cluster, run the command from within that connection.

There is a free self-paced lab on Amazon Redshift available at [qwikLABS](https://qwiklabs.com/) -- just search for Redshift. That will give you an introduction to connecting into and using REdshift.

Comment: How to automate it using any of the AWS services? Tried with AWS Lambda, I'm a python guy, but the native solution by AWS is using Node.js, which I am really not familiar with. What to do?

Comment: @AakashBasu You will need to connect to the database via JDBC. Since Redshift is based on PostgreSQL, you can use [psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/).

Answer (score 1):

COPY command is to be run from SQL client, like SQL Workbench.